# Spring Boot: Execute SQL

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

hello i just built a query in my method which return an sql query, the sql query is in a variable of type string which is in parameter but I can't seem to execute it with @Query please that must I do !

code interface JPA REPOSITORY :

```
@Query(requete)
Iterable<Closerfprfx> findAllrequete(String requete);
```

error :

> requete cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

you can not write a variable in @Query annotations.
you should write it directly like "select * from foo f"

Comment: please can you tell me what i should to do now i need to execute my  variable  , because this variable contains my SQL query

Comment: you can able to define a private static final String variable then use it in @Query annotation.